# POSTGRESQL = error data return from SPLIT_PART in trigger function

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I have a series of query that used to generate a unique value called uwi when I enter a Decimal degree coordinate (longitude and latitude). its combination from several data.
first I need to convert DD coordinate to DMS format
I reproduce this in dummy table named logic :

```
INSERT INTO public."logic"("DMSS")
SELECT (ST_AsLatLonText('POINT (' || cast(surface_longitude as text)|| ' '
||cast(surface_latitude as text) ||')', 'D M S.SSS C')) from well;
</code>
```

result

```
<code>
st_aslatlontext             |
----------------------------|
8 58 4.431 S 77 26 8.335 E  |
9 21 16.812 S 68 14 11.237 W|
7 20 43.531 S 88 27 23.851 E|
</code>
```

Then I need to arrange the coordinate to this format using split_part:

`select
SPLIT_PART(logic."DMSS"::text, ' ', 4)
||SPLIT_PART(logic."DMSS"::text, ' ', 1)
||SPLIT_PART(logic."DMSS"::text, ' ', 2)
||SPLIT_PART(logic."DMSS"::text, ' ', 3)
||'.'
||SPLIT_PART(logic."DMSS"::text, ' ', 8)
||SPLIT_PART(logic."DMSS"::text, ' ', 5)
||SPLIT_PART(logic."DMSS"::text, ' ', 6)
||SPLIT_PART(logic."DMSS"::text, ' ', 7) from logic ;`

result

`?column?            |
--------------------|
S8584431.E77268335  |
S92116812.W681411237|
S72043531.E882723851|`

combining with other data it should be like this to dummy table LOGIC :

```
    UPDATE logic
    SET "uwi" = '062.0001.00.'||SPLIT_PART(logic."DMSS"::text, ' ', 4)||SPLIT_PART(logic."DMSS"::text, ' ', 1)||SPLIT_PART(logic."DMSS"::text, ' ', 2)||regexp_replace(SPLIT_PART(logic."DMSS"::text, ' ', 3),'(\d)\.(\d)','\1\2')||'.'||SPLIT_PART(logic."DMSS"::text, ' ', 8)||SPLIT_PART(logic."DMSS"::text, ' ', 5)||SPLIT_PART(logic."DMSS"::text, ' ', 6)||regexp_replace(SPLIT_PART(logic."DMSS"::text, ' ', 7),'(\d)\.(\d)','\1\2');
```

FINAL RESULT

`uwi                              |
---------------------------------|
062.0001.00.S8584431.E77268335   |
062.0001.00.S92116812.W681411237 |
062.0001.00.S72043531.E882723851 |`

but when I reproduce this in the table named well
as trigger AFTER INSERT function

```
<code>
DECLARE 

    BEGIN
         IF tg_op='INSERT' THEN 
       CREATE TEMP TABLE dms_temp ON COMMIT DROP AS
       SELECT (ST_AsLatLonText('POINT (' || cast(new.surface_longitude as text)|| ' ' ||     cast(new.surface_latitude as text) ||')', 'D M S.SSS C')) 
        from well w;

INSERT INTO PUBLIC."well"( uwi ) 
SELECT 
'062.' 
|| CASE 
            WHEN w.primary_source = 'PEP' THEN '0001' ELSE'0002' 
     END 
        || '.' 
        || '00.' 
        || SELECT SPLIT_PART(dms_temp."st_aslatlontext"::text, ' ', 4) 
                ||SPLIT_PART(dms_temp."st_aslatlontext"::text, ' ', 1) 
                ||SPLIT_PART(dms_temp."st_aslatlontext"::text, ' ', 2)
                ||regexp_replace(SPLIT_PART(dms_temp."st_aslatlontext"::text, ' ', 3),'(\d)\.(\d)','\1\2') 
                ||'.'
                ||SPLIT_PART(dms_temp."st_aslatlontext"::text, ' ', 8) 
                ||SPLIT_PART(dms_temp."st_aslatlontext"::text, ' ', 5) 
                ||SPLIT_PART(dms_temp."st_aslatlontext"::text, ' ', 6) 
                ||regexp_replace(SPLIT_PART(dms_temp."st_aslatlontext"::text, ' ', 7),'(\d)\.(\d)','\1\2') 
                from dms_temp)
        FROM well as w where ; 
 END IF;
 RETURN NEW;
drop table dms_temp;
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
</code>
```

I get an error **more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression**
this table is the main data table as reference for other table

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: thanks for the advice, I'll try minimalize it